# Specifying "and not" qualification in Google Analytics

Tags: syntax, google-analytics

I'm new to GA and have a query submitted to pull data via the GA api.  I'm trying to combine to event label qualifications using an AND NOT condition as follows.

```
ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;!ga:eventLabel==Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query
```

This fails.  Is my syntax wrong?  The statement:

```
ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;ga:eventLabel==Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query
```

does work, and as I understand it, !=NOT and ;=AND.  So I would have thought this would succeedd.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: OK, well I found that just flipping it round as:  !ga:eventLabel==Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query;ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2 works.  But it would still be nice to know how to have the negative assertion in the 2nd clause with the AND NOT I originally attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the not equal to expression !=

```
ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;ga:eventLabel!=Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query
```

There's not as far as I'm aware a NOT expression in the way you are using it.